# Could anyone technically see my requests with TOR if the person has access to my router?

Tags: tor, wireshark, packet, sniffing

I was wondering if someone could sniff the packets I send via my computer with something like Wireshark I guess even if I use TOR and the person could access the router like stated.

Answer (score 2):

The communication between Tor's **[exit nodes](https://hackertarget.com/tor-exit-node-visualization/)** and the Internet is not different from normal traffic which thing makes Tor also prone to MITM attacks. Entry nodes do not cause a problem, but exit nodes do.

To answer straight forward to your question. it depends on what you mean exactly by *see my requests*. In practice, by design TOR is such that locating the source of such request sthrough the network should be difficult to determine, including your typical case.

However relying on unencrypted protocols (such as sending emails using SMTP) leads to your TOR requests being able to be entirely monitored (or *seen*, in your own vocabulary).

Comment: While your answer is factually correct, it doesn't really answer the question unless the asker happens to know the difference between an entry node and an exit node (and many, perhaps most, Tor users do not).

Answer (score 1):

The traffic between your computer and the TOR entry node is encrypted, so it is not possible for someone to see the unencrypted content of your TOR traffic between your PC and the entry node.

The traffic between the TOR exit node and the site you are accessing is not always encrypted (depends on the site), so it would be possible for somebody to sniff and see that traffic in unencrypted form.

Comment: Why do you type Tor as ToR?  The acronym is properly Tor or even perhaps TOR, but not ToR -- The Onion Router.  ToR only makes sense in lowercase-vowel leetspeak :)

Comment: You are right :) I don't know where I got that from. Will edit...

Comment: And the entry node is my router?

Comment: @Takowski No, the entry node is the host through which your computer connect to TOR. That means, the first host/node in the chain of TOR nodes.

Comment: So someone can still see whatever I request through TOR with a wiresharklike program if the person has access to my router?

Comment: @Takoeski No, because the connection between your computer and the entry node is encrypted.